# Verify that method is called after retrofit callback response arrives

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2

I have this simple DataInteractor which fetches a JsonObject from an api. When the data is not null, I save it locally just in case next time the request fails I can load it from there. I want to create a unit test which checks that when the response is not empty I actually call the method which backs up the information (sharedPreferencesManager.setLocalBackup()).

I've done unit testing only once or twice and for much simpler cases. I've found this links but I honestly feel I'm missing something...well...cause I haven't been able to implement the test, basically.

[Android test method called after presenter executes retrofit call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713462/android-test-method-called-after-presenter-executes-retrofit-call)

[Unit Testing in Retrofit for Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160055/unit-testing-in-retrofit-for-callback)

My Interactor:

```
public class DataInteractorImpl implements MainActivityContract.DataInteractor {

private SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager;

private Retrofit retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.nytimes.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

public DataInteractorImpl(SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager){
    this.sharedPreferencesManager = sharedPreferencesManager;
}

@Override
public void getNoticeArrayList(final OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener) {

    // RetrofitInstance interface
    DataInteractorService dataService = retrofit.create(DataInteractorService.class);

    Call<JsonObject> call = dataService.getNewsData(getCurrentDateYYYYMMDD());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            // if the response is not null, try to process it. Otherwise check the local backup
            if(response.body() != null){
                sharedPreferencesManager.setLocalBackup(response.body().toString());
            }
            onFinishedListener.onFinished(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            //check the local backup, return the backup if there is one
            if(sharedPreferencesManager.getLocalBackup() != null) {
                onFinishedListener.onFinished(sharedPreferencesManager.getLocalBackup());
            } else {
                onFinishedListener.onFailure(t);
            }
        }
    });
}

private String getCurrentDateYYYYMMDD(){
    Date date = new Date();
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
}
```

}

Any and help could be very useful.
Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: You can use a tool like Mockito or EasyMock to generate *mocked* instances of your classes. They do this by dynamically generating code which talks to the mocking library rather than calling the real implementation. What you do is tell mocking library to *expect* certain calls to happen on the mock object. You can even provide it values to return when a particular method is called. ex in easymock I can write `sharedPreferencesManager = createMock(SharedPreferencesManager.class); expect(sharedPreferencesManager.getLocalBackup()).andReturn(localBackup)`

Comment: Another option. the anonymous class `new Callback<JsonObject>()` does not need to be an anonymous class. You could create this as a named class and test the `onResponse` and `onFailure` methods independent of `getNoticeArrayList`.

Comment: @flakes Yep, that made it pretty easier to implement the test. Thanks!